# Check the type of a vector variable in R

Tags: r

How can I tell apart a vector of characters from a character in R?

Both `typeof(c("a", "b", "c"))` and `typeof("a")` return `'character'`.

Comment: They are the same, except for their length. `"a"` is a character vector of length 1.

Comment: Is a string a vector of characters then? Is it also true that `c(c("a", "b"))` is the same as `c(c("a"), c("b"))` and `c(c('a"))` is the same as `"a"`?

Comment: R doesn't have a separate "string" type. Yes, `c(c("a", "b"))` is the same as `c(c("a"), c("b"))`. You can check that with `?identical` (`identical(c(c("a", "b")), c(c("a"), c("b")))`)

Comment: I'm afraid not: `c("a", "b") == "ab"` returns `FALSE FALSE`

Comment: What are you trying to say?

Comment: How can I use `?identical`?  BTW, `c(c("a")) == "a"` evaluates to true.

Comment: Type `?identical` into your console and read the documentation. While you're at it, also read `?vector`

Comment: Or take a look at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html

Comment: Thanks, I'm just surprised that `identical(c("a", "b"), "ab")` doesn't evaluate to `TRUE`. It means that both `c("a", "b")`, `"ab"` are of type character, are of equal length, are made of the same characters, but are different.

Comment: Why would you expect `c("a", "b") == "ab"` to be `TRUE`? What is your question exactly?

Comment: Are you thinking that `c()` is concatenate? c("a", "b") is length 2.

Comment: No, I'm thinking that `c()` is a vector, which I thought would be a separate type in R. Apparently it isn't, since `typeof(c("a"))` returns `character`. Consider `c("a", "b")`. This is a value of type `character`. It's composed of 2 elements, "a" and "b". Consider `"ab"`. This is a value of type `character`. It's composed of 2 elements "a" and "b". Same length, same elements, same type. Different values. I'm just really surprised.

Comment: `"ab"` is not composed of 2 elements. Its a character string that contains `ab`.

Comment: Both "a" and "an" are strings and in r would be character vectors of length 1. They are not the same strings nor is either one a vector of length two with "a" as the first element and  "n" as the second.  `c("an")[1] == "an"`  TRUE     `c("an")[1] == "a"`   FALSE

Comment: Also `c()` is a function not a vector. It's function for creating vectors of any length and type.

Comment: @docendodiscimus thank you for your explanation and the links. Turns out that a more informative way to query about a type of a value is to use `str` as opposed to `typeof`

Comment: Why all the downvotes? This seems like a perfectly understandable misunderstanding for a beginner user of R to have, simplified and phrased adequately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In R integer or character or double don't really exist. Everything (or to be more correct, every atomic data) is a vector. Thus if `a = 1L`, then `a` is not an integer but a vector of integers with a length of 1.

Both tests return `character`. You can test the length of the vector.

You can read [Data Structures, a chapter of "Adavanced R"](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html) to learn more.

Comment: Strictly speaking, everything is not a vector.  Language objects, such as functions, are not vectors.  You refer to 'atomic' data types here.

Comment: Strictly speaking you're right. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly because R is a language created to work with data and do statistics everything is considered a vector, matrix or list (there are also constants but set those aside).   Vectors and matrices all have classes (or types), which are more similar to what you would see in other languages.   What some other languages call strings R calls characters.  Character values in a vector or matrix can be any length, they can be a single character "a" or they can be the whole text of *War and Peace*.  This is very different than the idea of a string array (or character array etc) in other languages.  This is because people are using these as data to be analyzed in a statistical context.